# download the last created file in S3 folder

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to download the last created file in S3 folder.

Example S3 PATH:

```
my_Bucket/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/folder_4/str_str2_2021_03_str3.csv
my_Bucket/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/folder_4/str_str2_2023_04_str3.csv
my_Bucket/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/folder_4/str_str2_2022_05_str3.csv
my_Bucket/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/folder_4/str_str2_2021_05_str3.csv
```

I should download the last created file, from this list for example the file: `str_str2_2023_04_str3.csv` should be downloaded.

I created a method `get_file_folders()` that get all the files in the `folder_4`:

```
str_str2_2021_03_str3.csv
str_str2_2023_04_str3.csv
str_str2_2021_03_str3.csv
str_str2_2021_05_str3.csv
```

```py
session_root = boto3.Session(region_name='eu-west-3', profile_name='my_profile')
s3_client = session_root.client('s3')

def get_file_folders(s3_client, bucket_name, prefix=""):
    file_names = []
    folders = []
    file_name_child = []
    biggest_number = []

    default_kwargs = {
        "Bucket": bucket_name,
        "Prefix": prefix
    }
    next_token = ""

    while next_token is not None:
        updated_kwargs = default_kwargs.copy()
        if next_token != "":
            updated_kwargs["ContinuationToken"] = next_token

        response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(**default_kwargs)
        contents = response.get("Contents")

        for result in contents:
            key = result.get("Key")
            if key[-1] == "/":
                folders.append(key)
            else:
                file_names.append(key)
            

        next_token = response.get("NextContinuationToken")
        for file in file_names:
            file_name_child = file.split("/")[4]
            print(file_name_child)
            
            #for file in file_name_child:     
            
            
    return file_names, folders
```

I'm looking for the download method to modify it to download only the last created file:

```py
def download_files(s3_client, bucket_name, local_path, file_names, folders):

    local_path = Path(local_path)

    for folder in folders:
        folder_path = Path.joinpath(local_path, folder)
        folder_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    for file_name in file_names:
        file_path = Path.joinpath(local_path, file_name)
        file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        s3_client.download_file(
            bucket_name,
            file_name,
            str(file_path)
        )
```

Do you have please an idea how to modify my download method to download the last created file or do you have another solution?

Thank you

Comment: Each time you want to download the last created file, you will need to check timestamp of every file. A better solution is that you maintain a record (a txt file in S3 or DynamoDB) where you write the path of the last S3 file changed. When you want to download it, you simply read the last changed file path and download it.

Comment: Could you please write your solution on python please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to determine which object has the latest `LastModified` date, as opposed to extracting the date from the Key (filename) of the object, then you could use:

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'bucket-name-here'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

latest = None

for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.all():
    if (latest is None or object.last_modified > latest) and not object.key.endswith('/'):
        latest = object.last_modified
        latest_key = object.key

print(latest_key)

target_filename = latest_key.split('/')[-1] # Assume you just want the filename portion
s3_resource.Object(BUCKET, latest_key).download_file(target_filename)
```

Comment: I'm using s3_client = session_root.client('s3'), I got S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket
I want to determine which object has the latest LastModified and download it, if you have seen my first method return all the files in the subfolders, I want download the last created file.

Comment: Please note that my example code is using `boto3.resource('s3')` rather than `boto3.client('s3')`. The 'resource' method offers a more Pythonic way of interfacing with S3 and handles pagination automatically, so the code is a lot cleaner.

Comment: I'm using session_root because, I have a profile_name to pass, there are 3 profiles types that we have to connect to AWS dashboard.

Comment: after testing the code, finally it download the first object in the bucket, it doesn't loup all the objects.

Comment: I have updated my sample code to show how to use `session` with `resource()`.

Comment: @mlflow If you think that the code is not looping through all objects, then add some debugging statements such as `print(object.key)` before the `if` statement to figure out what is happening.

Comment: it loup all the bucket objects. But it download the first file founded in the first sub-object of the bucket, knowing that I'm looking to download the last created file in a specific path in the bucket.

Comment: Ah! I think I know the problem... I had the sign flipped the wrong way. I have updated it to use `last_modified > latest` -- please try that. (It was previously `last_modified < latest`)